# 64bit hex to decimal in C

Tags: c, hex, decimal, converters, wireshark

I am reading in a pcap file from Wireshark and storing the data in 8bits using u_char. One portion of the data is in 64bits, so I have eight 8bit numbers that I need to combine into/ read as one 64bit number and then convert it into decimal. 
For example, this is what I currently have

```
Hex: 3f e2  da  2f 8b  de  c5  f4
Dec: 63 226 218 47 139 222 197 244
```

and this is what I currently want,

```
Hex: 3fe2da2f8bdec5f4
Dec: .589134
```

To combine the 8 1bytes, I have tried:

```
long long int a;
a = (data[j] << 56) | (data[j+1] << 48) | (data[j+2] << 40) | (data[j+3] << 32) | (data[j+4] << 24) | (data[j+5] << 16) | (data[j+6] << 8) | data[j+7];
printf("%lld", a);

output: -1073815553
```

Help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The period part is suggesting it is not integer at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like OP wants to overlay an 8-byte integer with a [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) `double`.

Such code is portable to many machines, but is certainly not portable to all C machines as is assumes many things like the form of a `double`.

```
int main(void) {
  union {
    double d;
    unsigned long long ull;
  } u;
  u.d = 0.589134;
  printf("%016llX\n", u.ull);
  u.ull = 0x3fe2da2f8bdec5f4;
  printf("%lf\n", u.d);
  return 0;
}

3FE2DA2F8BDEC5F4
0.589134
```

Comment: Yep. http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?hexadecimal=3FE2DA2F8BDEC5F4

Comment: @Eugene Sh.Nice link to web-site and with "0.589134" value.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for. My main issue is taking 8 1byte numbers and merging them into 1 8byte number.

Comment: @mchoy25 `u.ull = Hex[0]*1LL << 56 + Hex[1]*1LL << 48 + Hex[2]*1LL << 40 + ... Hex[7]*1LL << 0;` is a portable, endian independent method.  To get better answers, post what you have tried.

Comment: @chux What you've written is similar to what I've tried. I edited my post to show what I've done.

Comment: Don't forget the result is `double`, not `long long`.

Comment: @mchoy25 `long long int a = (data[j] << 56) | (data[j+1] << 48) ...` is likely a problem as `data[j]` is narrower than a 64-bit unsigned integer and shifting by the width or more is undefined.  Code needs to shift a 64-bit type. `data[0]*1LL << 56` would do that as the product `data[0]*1LL` is at least 64-bits _before_ the shift.

Comment: @mchoy25  (it would be better to post a complete example).  Let us assume `data[]` is an array of 8-bit unsigned integers and that `int` is 32-bit.  With `data[j] << 56`, code performs the usual integer promotions on `data[j]` and  `56`before the shift, thus making the values `int`.  Since `int` is 32-bit on your machine, shifting by `56` is undefined behavior and maybe just does a shift by `56-32` or `24`.  Or-ing all these 32-bit values results in a 32-bit value, which is then assigned to a 64-bit result `a`.

Comment: Thanks. You two have been very helpful.